# VMWare VM does not see a Shared Folder

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation

My OS Windows, I have VMWare and VM with Ubuntu 21.10 inside.

All works fine. But I'd like to have a Shared folder to exchange files.
I have created in Windows the folder: SharedUFolder.

Then go to VM Settings->Options: Shared Folders: Enabled (Always) , then Add and added Windows SharedUFolder. Ok. How to access this Shared folder in Ubuntu? I do not find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux terminal write the following command:

1- vmware-hgfsclient *

You should see your shared folder name then write:

2- sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other

Now you will find your shared folder mounted at /mnt/hgfs

Comment: clear and simple !

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this:

**Easy way:**   (recommended)

In Linux, File Explorer, map a folder in Windows.

SMB://Windows_name_or_IP/folder and authenticate.

This works in my Ubuntu VMware VM and in my Kali VMware VM and my Windows 10 / 11 Host.

Once mapped, you can exchange files between the two systems.

This is easier (IMHO) than Shared Folders (*which work best in Windows Guests*)

**Using SAMBA (not as easy):**

Install SAMBA.
Make a samba share from which to share files (mkdir /home/username/sambashare/ .
Set up smb.conf with browsing and user names.

Samba allows you to start in Windows and map a folder in Linux. It is trickier than the Easy Way and I recommend the easy way.

(Ref:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba )